# Click on image to access another page on website using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i am trying to automate clicking an image on a website. **The below is the code from the website.**

```
<div class="home-page-button">
<div>
<a name="ContinueToBookingSystem" formaction="/Home/ContinueToBookingSystem">
<img src="/public/img/icons/home-plane.png" alt="Continue to booking system"/>
</a>
</div>
<div>Continue to booking system</div>
```

i keep receiving the below error.

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[@class='home-page-button]//a[@alt='Continue to booking system']' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

This is what i have attempted.

```
ctbs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='home-page-button]//a[@alt='Continue to booking system']")
ctbs.click()
```

All help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling driver.find_element**s**_by_xpath.

Try `driver.find_element_by_xpath` without the **s**. Also you are missing a closed single quote for `@class='home-page-button'`.

```
ctbs = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='home-page-button']//img[@alt='Continue to booking system']")
ctbs.click()
```

**Update:** Changed "a" tag to "img" in the `xpath`.

Comment: Thanks, i've updated the code as per your answer. Unfortunately, i'm still getting an error.


Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='home-page-button']//a[@alt='Continue to booking system']"}

Comment: Can you share the website URL please?

Comment: unfortunately not as it requires a log in. i can send you more of the code if that helps?

Comment: Had another look at your html. Please see update in answer.

Comment: i appreciate the help! Still receiving an error though :(


Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='home-page-button']//img[@alt='Continue to booking system']"}

Comment: If you look further up in your html, beyond what you have posted in the question, do you see any iframe tag? (You can use CTRL + F in your Chrome F12 screen to search)

Comment: There's nothing in there associated with iframe? i've checked all the code on the page.

Comment: Do you REALLY need to click on an image, rather than for example a button with an image overlayed? I wonder if there's a simpler way like just `ctbs = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='home-page-button']")`  or `ctbs = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@alt='Continue to booking system']")`

Comment: By selecting the image this takes me through to a booking system.

i've tried both methods above and it still seems to be erroring.

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='home-page-button']"}

Comment: Please update the question and add the entire html source. One way to do this is `html = driver.page_source
print(html)`
And copy the contents here.

Comment: unable to post html source apologies.is there any way to do this using the img src?